# Edit link is broken after editing a post when a pending edit is rejected by Community

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

When a pending edit is suggested and submitted while another edit is taking place, the edit link is broken after saving the original edit.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Begin editing a post (I was the creator of the post, not sure if this is required)
2. While editing, another user without edit privileges submits a suggested edit for the same post.
3. *I believe that* the suggested edit receives one approval vote. (Also not sure if this is required.)
4. I save my edit, and [Community automatically rejects the pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/563153). However, the edit link is displayed as `edit(1)`, and does nothing when you click on it.

Comment: I've noticed that when there is a suggested edit, it just *always* displays `edit (1)` as well, even if there's 0 or 2 votes on it, and even here on Meta where only one vote is even required...

Comment: May I know the reason for the close votes on this? Do you have any info to share regarding the no-repro aspect of this bug?

Comment: @TIPS good question. It's terribly complicated to reproduce, but can't find anything saying it's fixed by now. Voted now to Leave Open.