# Is there a way to access the older review tools for processing the edit queue?

Tags: discussion, review

There is a javascript bug that is preventing me from rejecting edits and sending a comment to the editor on why the edit is being rejected.

[Unable to reject an edit without an error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144912/unable-to-reject-an-edit-without-an-error) or [Cannot reject suggested edits with a custom reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason)

Until this gets sorted, is there a way to get back to the older code that worked? Perhaps site.stackexchange.com/review-old or something?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, `/review/suggested-edits/` now redirects to `/review-beta/suggested-edits/`

Comment: Thanks @ben - I couldn't remember the older path but figured if the devs kept it around perhaps someone would know.

Comment: You used to be able to use both simultaneously...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and even if there were, it wouldn't matter. The new suggested edit review method has already been pushed to regular suggested edits as well (like you'd see straight from a post, which I assume is causing [the `edit (1)` bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144847/edit-link-is-broken-after-editing-a-post-when-a-pending-edit-is-rejected-by-comm#comment413276_144847)). No matter where you go, you're going to see that same suggested edit review screen and the custom reason isn't going to work.

[image: Mooowaaahhhhaaahaaa!]

Answer (score 0):

Even if all review queues are "converted", I'd propose to have a way accessing the "old-style" review tools. With the new review-beta, one gets shown only 1 question at a time and is *forced* to decide upon this. There's no way to postpone ones decision on a more difficult question. This may lead to "trigger-happiness", where in this case one would just push any button to "see something more useful" (in ones own opinion, of course).

I watched myself working with both systems in parallel and found: I like the new system when it comes to "vote for closure" (decide whether something is a dupe, off-topic, whatever). Here I either have an opinion or not (the latter mostly when I'm not familiar with the given topic). But speaking about quality, it gets harder -- and I find myself reverting to the "old-style" review system, where I can pick items freely, while still being able to check on the other ones later.

It would be great to have a link to the old review system available, say, at the bottom of the "Help improve the site" box. This way one can switch between systems and see which feels more comfortable. Which would also help avoiding above mentioned "trigger-happiness".

**EDIT:** To underline what I mean, let me quote from another question here: *As it stands now, I rarely touch the edit queue unless I'm really bored because I don't want to have to wade through a ton of questions that I can't necessarily help with.* This describes quite well my feelings: For certain review queues I feel I could be much more helpful using the old system ;)